# Can you help to analyze the pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain me what this javascript patter actually looking for?

```
var pattern = /^\/.*\/$/i;
```

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com/#javascript type in regex and on a right you will see explanation.

Comment: Edin M.,thx ,that is cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks for strings that:

- start with /
- end with /
- have zero or more char (any char) between the two /

Please note:

- ^ means start of the pattern
- $ mean end of the pattern
- . mean any char
- * mean zero or more

Comment: Looks to me like a regex for regex.

Comment: Yes ! but also a regexp for a directory path

Comment: it doesn't work for "D:/test/dir1/", need to change it to /^.*\/.*\/$/i

Comment: you are right, it's  for a unix/linux/cygwin path :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's he best [tutorial on RegEx](http://regexone.com/) I've found on the Internet. You might've solved your problem just by looking at the table to the right on the page of the tutorial. Just spend an hour on this. It helped me a lot!

In the example you've provided:

```
^…$     Starts and ends
.   Any Character
*   Zero or more repetitions
```

Comment: it looks appropriate for me;)